# Can't connect to Oracle from a windows service (error: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve service name (12154) )

Tags: oracle, windows-services

**LATEST Update (Nov 2 2011 9AM)**
I tried running tnsping from the service and it WORKS!
However i still get error 12154 when i try to connect.  I'm completely confused now, i can't understand how tnsping could work fine but the connection is unable to resolve the service name.

For some reason when i run the following code from a windows service (on a timer event) I get the error: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve service name (12154)

When i run the exact same code from a windows form app, it connects just fine.  Both the service and the app are running under my account, so there is no difference in the account permissions.
I'm baffled as to why the service fails, can anyone shed some light on this please?

```
string connectionString =     ";DSN=o1;UID=SCOTT;PWD=TIGER;DBQ=ORCL;DBA=W;APA=T;EXC=F;FEN=T;QTO=T;FRC=10;FDL=10;LOB=T;RST=T;GDE=F;FRL=F;BAM=IfAllSuccessful;MTS=F;MDI=F;CSR=F;FWC=F;PFC=10;TLO=0;";
        OdbcConnection cnn;
        cnn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
        try
        {
            cnn.Open();
            myEventLog.WriteEntry("Connection SUCCEEDED!!!");
            cnn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string mes = "Connection FAILED!!!" + ex.Message;
            myEventLog.WriteEntry(mes);
        }
```

Updates:

1) I've tried with both system and user dsn, both have the same behaviour

2) I added a TNS_ADMIN to the system environment variables to make sue it can find the tnsnames.ora file.  This did not change the behaviour.

New Updates (Nov 1 2011):

1) A lot of the suggestions have involved putting the ip address of the Oracle server in the connection string to bypass the tnsnames.ora file. Unfortunately the app has to work with a user set oracle connection, so we don't have any of that information.  All i have to work with is a DSN.  I have to make it connect from a windows service using an Oracle DSN.

New Updates (Nov 2 2011):
1) It looks like the service IS successfully reading the tnsnames.ora file.  I ran process monitor and got these lines:

```
7:52:54.4365217 AM  OracleService.exe   4624    CreateFile          C:\oracle\ora92\network\Names\sdns.ora  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: n/a
7:52:54.4368466 AM  OracleService.exe   4624    CreateFile  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\tnsnames.ora    NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
7:52:54.4371203 AM  OracleService.exe   4624    CreateFile  C:\oracle\ora92\network\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora  SUCCESS Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
7:52:54.4372693 AM  OracleService.exe   4624    QueryBasicInformationFile   C:\oracle\ora92\network\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora  SUCCESS CreationTime: 01/11/2011 3:10:08 PM, LastAccessTime: 01/11/2011 3:10:08 PM, LastWriteTime: 01/11/2011 3:10:42 PM, ChangeTime: 01/11/2011 3:18:44 PM, FileAttributes: A
7:52:54.4372866 AM  OracleService.exe   4624    CloseFile   C:\oracle\ora92\network\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora  SUCCESS 
7:52:54.4375418 AM  OracleService.exe   4624    CreateFile  C:\oracle\ora92\network\ADMIN   SUCCESS Desired Access: Read Data/List Directory, Synchronize, Disposition: Open, Options: Directory, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
7:52:54.4375857 AM  OracleService.exe   4624    QueryDirectory  C:\oracle\ora92\network\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora  SUCCESS Filter: tnsnames.ora, 1: tnsnames.ora
7:52:54.4376192 AM  OracleService.exe   4624    CloseFile   C:\oracle\ora92\network\ADMIN   SUCCESS 
7:52:54.4377770 AM  OracleService.exe   4624    CreateFile  C:\oracle\ora92\network\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora  SUCCESS Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
7:52:54.4379306 AM  OracleService.exe   4624    ReadFile    C:\oracle\ora92\network\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora  SUCCESS Offset: 0, Length: 337, Priority: Normal
7:52:54.4380061 AM  OracleService.exe   4624    ReadFile    C:\oracle\ora92\network\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora  END OF FILE Offset: 337, Length: 4,096
7:52:54.4380276 AM  OracleService.exe   4624    CloseFile   C:\oracle\ora92\network\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora  SUCCESS 
7:52:54.4385823 AM  OracleService.exe   4624    CreateFile  C:\oracle\ora92\network\ADMIN\ldap.ora  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
```

So does anyone have any idea why it might be failing after reading the tnsnames.ora file?  Thanks

Comment: Since it works when you run it, I'm going to assume your tnsnames.ora is configured correctly. Is the ODBC DSN you're connecting to setup as a system DNS or a user DSN?

Comment: I've tried with both system and user dsn, both have the same behaviour.

Comment: Which version of windows do you use ?

Comment: i'm on Windows 7 but as far as i know it happens on all current versions of windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'm going to answer my own question here just to keep the final resolution separate from the helpful suggestions that led me to it.  The post referenced by Nicola )once I read it carefully) turned out to have the answer.  My service was running from Program Files(x86) and the oracle driver can NOT handle ( ) in the path of the calling app.
I moved my service to D:\ServiceTest and it works fine.
My problem now is that I don't think our app can be moved out of Program Files (x86).
Thank you all for your help, I appreciate everyone's input but I will have to give the bounty to Nicola, as he pointed me to the post that contained the answer.
Thanks again for all your help

Answer (score 6):

Environment variables you define in the corresponding dialog are not available to Windows services. One thing you can try is to expand your connection string as described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704772/windows-service-in-net-cannot-resolve-tns-service-name). Other suggestions from the same post may be applicable.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I'm sorry but i don't understand Oracle or connect strings very well, so i tried what is suggested in your link but when i change my connectstring to:Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.121.200)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL)));User Id=SCOTT;Password=TIGER;      i get the error: [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified   and i get it in both the app and in the service, so i've done something wrong, b but i can't figure out what.  Thanks

Comment: Did you try out the other suggestions in the question I linked? The answer from @crb seems relevant to your problem.

Comment: Hi Nicola, and thanks!  At least i've made a little progress so far.  I hadn't seen crb's suggestions and now that i have i ran process monitor and found that surprisingly the service DOES seem to be finding and reading the correct tnsnames.ora file.  So there must be some other issue that the service is having that the app doesn't.  I'll post the relevant linces from proces monitor that show the service successfully reading the tnsnames.ora file.  Thanks

Comment: I am also having same issue.. I cannot expand my connection string https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53889794/read-tnsnames-ora-when-wcf-service-hosted-in-windows-service

Answer (score 2):

It probably does not find the tnsnames.ora file. Make sure that the same environment variables are set when you start the service.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Just to check and make sure i added the TNS_ADMIN environment variable to the system variables and pointed it to the orahome directory and restarted the service.  That, as far as i know, should ensure that the service can find the tnsnames.ora file and yet i still get the same error.

Comment: I also have same issue. I update my TNS_ADMIN env variable and made sure I have tnsnames.ora file there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53889794/read-tnsnames-ora-when-wcf-service-hosted-in-windows-service

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the service account has permissions to read the tnsnames.ora file.
Also in sqlnet.ora try removing NTS from SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES if it is there.

If your are still struggling try using ezconnect to bypass tns names all together
ex: //ip.of.server/sid

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/EZCONNECT

Comment: i have tried ezconnect and can't get it to work from either the app or the service so i'll have to understadn it better.  However even if it worked i woudln't be able to use it as this is a user defined oracle connection so all i have to connect with is a dsn.

Comment: I assume DSN=o1 is an odbc connection defined on your computer.
When you edit the odbc connection in "TNS service name" replace whatever you currently have with //ip.addr/SID where ip.addr is the ip of your oracle machine and SID the SID or database name of the oracle instance.

Comment: Also make sure you have the following in your sqlnet.ora file NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH=(ezconnect, tnsnames)
I've never had to use it myself but try adding it if it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

John C: A couple of things seemed odd to me. I hope I have not misunderstood your replies.

In the connection string in one of the replies, you got an error about the missing driver. To fix this you will have to mention the provider/driver since you are using the OdbcConnection and not an OracleConnection. The OracleConnection  that most people would use would implicitly point the to the driver. I assume you need to service to work across databases so the OdbcConnection is required. The [website](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle) gives a lot of examples for connection strings and I think you should find something that fits.

I would suggest you try

> **Driver={Microsoft ODBC for
>   Oracle}**;CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=server)(PORT=7001))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=myDb)));Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;

Another thing was the location that your TNS_ADMIN variable pointed to. You had mentioned that you pointed to OraHome. I just wanted to confirm that you pointed the variable to the **NETWORK** \ **ADMIN** folder within OraHome. I believe you will have to point to the folder where the file exists.

Finally I would suggest you try and take some of the parameters out of the connection string you have in the original post. It would reduce the variables that can affect the outcome, making it easier to debug. And have the environment variable which are configured for the user as system environment variables. Perhaps the reason you winforms application works is because of a variable defined for the user. I suspect that windows service may only use system variables.

> Driver={Oracle in
>   OraHome92};Server=myServerAddress;Dbq=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;

Comment: Thank you akhliss, i have tried simplifying the connection string but it still doesn't work.  I'm not going to spend much time trying connection strings that include the server ip directly because that won't help our app anyway, since we don't know the server ip (please see the updates on the question).  I appreciate your effort and welcome any other suggestions you might have.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem.

there was a '@' character in the password of my database. After I changed the password and remove that character, the problem has been fixed and the export operation has completed successfully.

[This link](http://www.techyv.com/questions/error-12154-oracle-database) was helpful in solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the TNS Name definition does not have spaces before the name in the tnsnames.ora