# Read TNSNAMES.ORA when WCF service hosted in Windows Service

Tags: c#, oracle, wcf

I have a **WCF service** which I am **hosting in Windows Service**. I made my Windows Service to Log On as Network Service. In my Windows service's App.config file, I am giving connection string like below

```
<connectionStrings>
     <add name="MyConnetcionString" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"
          connectionString="Data Source=tdb1;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;
          Persist Security Info=true;Pooling=false" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I am able to install and run Windows Service. I am also making sure my WCF service is running. But when I make client calls, I get below error on WCF service side

**ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified**

**My problem is my Windows Service ( hosting service ) is unable to read my tnsnames.ora**

I even changed my TNS_ADMIN environmental variable to a location in C drive where I have tnsnames.ora but its failing.

Everything works fine if I host my WCF service in a console application. But we want Windows service to host WCF service.

My service running from C:\Dept\ServerWindowsHost\bin\Debug

I saw below but did not work since **I cannot expand my connection string**. I tried expanding it and it works fine.

[Can't connect to Oracle from a windows service (error: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve service name (12154) )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206129/cant-connect-to-oracle-from-a-windows-service-error-ora-12154-tnscould-not)

**SOLUTION**

I was able to fix the issue. I used process monitor to solve the issue.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

It showed me clearly what locations my windows service is looking for tnsnames.ora. I simply copied tnsnames.ora to those folders and everything worked fine.

[image]

Comment: Do you have to use tnsnames.ora? What if you were to use a connection string for Oracle that eliminated the reliance on tnsnames.ora?

Comment: mason... I need to use tnsnames.ora. I expanded my connectionstring and it works but I need to use tnsnames.ora

Comment: Does Network Service have permissions to read your .ora file?

Comment: Popo... yes we gave it full access....